# Drop duplicates with a cache's rule

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-analysis

I have a dataframe with two columns (Id and Datetime), i have to drop duplicated rows related to the same id considering the datetime column. The rule is that I need to check subsequent dates, and if they're on the same day, or the day after (not 48 hours, but the day after, until 23:59:59), they need to be dropped.

I give an example below.

Original Dataframe

| ID | Datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 2023-05-01 10:00:00 |
| 100 | 2023-05-01 11:00:00 |
| 100 | 2023-05-01 15:00:00 |
| 100 | 2023-05-02 17:00:00 |
| 100 | 2023-05-02 23:59:59 |
| 100 | 2023-05-03 01:00:00 |
| 100 | 2023-05-03 05:00:00 |
| 200 | 2023-05-01 15:00:00 |
| 200 | 2023-05-01 18:00:00 |
| 200 | 2023-05-02 12:00:00 |
| 200 | 2023-05-03 07:00:00 |

Expected Dataframe

| ID | Datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 2023-05-01 10:00:00 |
| 100 | 2023-05-03 01:00:00 |
| 200 | 2023-05-01 15:00:00 |
| 200 | 2023-05-03 07:00:00 |

Sorry for my bad english!

I tried to shift lines, calculating the difference between the columns and assert a condition that satisfies the condition that i am looking for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to:

- "truncate" the datetimes
- group with a 2d frequency
- take the `.first()` of each group.

```
(df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df["Datetime"].dt.date))
   .groupby(["ID", pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="2d")])
   .first())
```

```
                          Datetime
ID  Date                          
100 2023-05-01 2023-05-01 10:00:00
    2023-05-03 2023-05-03 01:00:00
200 2023-05-01 2023-05-01 15:00:00
    2023-05-03 2023-05-03 07:00:00
```